# transform es6 to commonjs in memory and use it

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, commonjs

At this point

1. I have a file written in ES6 and used by create-react-app app.
2. I want to load that file in memory transform it to commonJS and use exported values in one of my scripts that needs to be commonJS.

What I have: (inspired by react-boilerplate scripts)

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const {
  transform
} = require('@babel/core');

const readFile = fileName =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(
      fileName,
      'utf8',
      (error, value) => (error ? reject(error) : resolve(value)),
    );
  });

const extractFromFile = async() => {
  const presets = [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        modules: false,
      },
    ],
    '@babel/preset-react'
  ];
  const plugins = [
    '@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs'
  ];

  const filename = './xyz.js';

  try {
    const code = await readFile(filename);

    const output = await transform(code, {
      filename,
      presets,
      plugins
    });

    // Here ... !!
    // if i write output.code to file and read it from, i can access the exported values
    // but if i try something like this: const foo = require(output.code) or any other
    // combination that i can think off, i get undefined or errors.

    console.log(output)

  }
}
```

The Question: How should one get exported values of that file without saving it first to file and required it back from it?

**EDIT:**

"...use exported values in one of my scripts that needs to be commonJS..."

What I try to achieve is to have a script that would extract react-intl messages from my project.

I found a very useful [script](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/blob/d19099afeff64ecfb09133c06c1cb18c0d40887e/internals/scripts/extract-intl.js) written by the react-boilerplate project people and used it in my project.

The file that I try to load is [i18n.js and in their project](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/blob/d19099afeff64ecfb09133c06c1cb18c0d40887e/app/i18n.js), it's written in commonJS with a comment

> IMPORTANT: This file is used by the internal build
>    *   script `extract-intl`, and must use CommonJS module syntax
>    *   You CANNOT use import/export in this file.

BUT: I use create-react-app and to my knowledge (and what I tested) I cannot use modules.exports as it breaks the 'yarn run build' script and I don't want to to eject the app.

Thanks

Comment: *"...use exported values in one of my scripts that needs to be commonJS..."* Out of curiosity, *why* does it "need" to be CommonJS? It seems like [an X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Maybe we could help you solve the underlying problem instead.

Comment: Are you using any kind of bundler? Any decent bundler should be able to support mixing ESM and CJS.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

I would probably approach this by trying to change the requirement, or by using a bundler.

But answering the question within the constraints listed, I think I'd use dynamic `import` in the CommonJS module. Dynamic import works outside ESM modules and is supported by all major modern browsers, thougn not sadly by Edge v44 and earlier ("Legacy Edge").

Dynamic import returns a promise that is fulfilled with the module namespace object of the ESM module (which has properties for its exports):

```
import("/path/to/module")
.then(mod => {
    // Use `mod.x` here
})
.catch(error => {
    // Handle module load error
});
```

You could even define a CommonJS wrapper for a module if you liked:

```
(async () => {
    module.exports = await import("/path/to/module");
})
.catch(error => {
    // Handle module load error
});
```

---

In your update to the question, you've said:

> The file that I try to load is i18n.js and in their project, it's written in commonJS with a comment
>
> > IMPORTANT: This file is used by the internal build * script extract-intl, and must use CommonJS module syntax * You CANNOT use import/export in this file.
>
> BUT: I use create-react-app and to my knowledge (and what I tested) I cannot use modules.exports as it breaks the 'yarn run build' script and I don't want to to eject the app.

That's fine, you should be able to **use** it via `import` syntax (with a bundler — in your case, Webpack, which is what create-react-app uses); all it says is that you can't use `import`/`export` syntax *within* the file.

If you install the file to `node_modules`, your create-react-app build should be able to use it, thanks to Webpack's module handling.